# Which one is the first argument in "Linearity in the first argument"?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the middle of the course, the lecturer is [using](https://youtu.be/HansIRlT0Dw?t=224) Linearity of the Inner Product to do some math, and I don't remember this clearly, so I searched a little bit.

the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) says

> Linearity in the first argument:

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\langle ax,y\rangle &=a\langle x,y\rangle \\\langle x+y,z\rangle &=\langle x,z\rangle +\langle y,z\rangle \end{aligned}}}$$

in the context, why only first argument has the Linearity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its correct. Linearity in the first argument means that for fixed $y\in V$, the mapping

$\langle \cdot,y\rangle:V\rightarrow K: x\mapsto\langle x,y\rangle$

is linear, where $V$ is a $K$-vector space. The linearity in the second argument can be defined similarly. But when working in Hilbert spaces over the complex numbers, one only has linearity in the first argument and anti-linearity in the second.

Comment: thank for your answer, in this concrete example, $\displaystyle x = \left[\begin{matrix}2\\1\\1\end{matrix}\right] \quad \displaystyle b = \left[\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right]$, using the dot product as inner product, $\langle \cdot,y\rangle = x^T \cdot b$, and what does V, K is?

Comment: Vector space $V={\Bbb R}^3$ and scalar field $K={\Bbb R}$. Here $\langle x,b\rangle = x^T\cdot b$ with $b$ fixed.

Comment: It is a matter of convention in which argument it is linear and in which it is antilinear. For some reason, mathematicians seem to prefer the first argument to be the linear one, while physicists prefer the second one to be the linear one.

Comment: Exactly, in my class on quantum computing and whatnot, I've use the physics notation which means linearity in the 2nd argument.